# Can not re-subscribe deleted member

Tags: mailchimp

When using MailChimp API v3, then delete a member using "DELETE" method

I can;t re-subscribe the same email, even when it not exists in list

it keep say

```
<email> is already a list member.  Use PUT to insert or update list members.
```

Answer (score 6):

I wrote Mail Chimp asking about this after having the same problem. They recently restructured how they handle deletions to stay compliant with local and international sending laws. Now when you delete a subscriber, the subscriber is technically removed from the list, but Mail Chimp is still storing it on their end. The status of this member is just changed from `'susbscribed'` to `''`. So you will see it removed from the list, but if you GET all members, you will see the deleted member. In order to re-subscribe them, you can just do a PUT call to update the subscribers status to `subscribed` from no status.

http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#edit-put_lists_list_id_members_subscriber_hash

Comment: I'm getting ""\"john@example.com\" is already in this list with a status of \"subscribed\"."" He was subscribed, but I deleted him. He's not showing up in the playground under members, and I even got curl up and running and examined the output of getting all members, not there either. So it is removed from the list, but unlike you, when I GOT all members, the deleted member was not there. How did you do it? How did you see the deleted member?

Comment: It's odd that you don't find these answers on the API Documentation and instead find them on SO even after 2 years! Thanks, this should be the accepted answer!